# multiple subscriptions ignoring messages [updated]

Tags: ros, kinect, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
My node is listening to 2 kinects on 8 topics for messages. Even though messages are published on all topics only 4 of the callbacks are invoked. I tried changing the LOOP_RATE, increased the QUEUE size but doesn't make a difference. Is there something I am doing wrong or missing?
Here's the code that I was running: [listener.cpp](http://ideone.com/uME4W)
And here are my launch files for kinects:
[Kinect1_openni_node.launch](http://ideone.com/GWOq8), [Kinect2_openni_node.launch](http://ideone.com/mbdkr), [kinect_frames1.launch](http://ideone.com/7olVB) , [kinect_frames2.launch](http://ideone.com/9NvEA)
Here's my rxgraph
[image: image description]
When I run listener.cpp , all I get is the following i.e. it skips messages from 4 topics

```
[ INFO] [1299768991.573907570]: Depth Image: [2]
[ INFO] [1299768991.580039704]: Kinect1 Depth Image: [6]
[ INFO] [1299768991.594992942]: Depth Points: [216]
[ INFO] [1299768991.598203115]: Depth Image: [2]
[ INFO] [1299768991.618901837]: Kinect1 Depth Points: [5]
[ INFO] [1299768991.622189841]: Kinect1 Depth Image: [6]
[ INFO] [1299768991.641956580]: Depth Points: [217]
[ INFO] [1299768991.646081980]: Depth Image: [2]
^C[ INFO] [1299768991.660327453]: Kinect1 Depth Points: [5]
```

Thanks for any help.
Best,
CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9361/multiple-subscriptions-ignoring-messages-%5Bupdated%5D/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-10**:
@Tully & @ Felix Endres: I've updated my question as requested. Please let me know your opinion. Thank you.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-09**:
It's impossible to say, unless you at least tell us which topics you subscribed to.

**Comment by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on 2011-03-09**:
Please add more information to help us debug.  Such as sample code, launch files, outputs of rxgraph, and appropriate rostopic hz.  This sounds like a configuration issue not a code issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what settings you have configured the Kinect with it does not necessarily publish on all advertised topics.  Some are mutually exclusive.

I recommend that you look at what settings you have configured using `rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui`  and the documentation in [openni_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-12**:
While this is true, i think these topics are not the mono/rgb image and the clouds. I have no better idea though.